# How to install software-properties-common on i386 20.04?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, 32-bit, docker

I'm running an i386/Ubuntu 20.04 image inside a docker container.

I'm running apt-get `install software-properties-common` and get the following:

```
software-properties-common : Depends: gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 (>= 1.1.0-2) but it is not installable
Depends: packagekit but it is not installable
```

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: By the way, where did you get a 32 bit image for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: It seems to be available when using Docker.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `i386` version of `gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0` was removed from [Ubuntu 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0).

You can grab its .deb package from [18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0).

Comment: `software-properties-common` is actually required for the add-apt-repository command. I'm not too sure why they would remove that on i386.

Comment: @bunjee Probably because Ubuntu does not support 32 bit (i386) architecture anymore. Launchpad refuses to build 32 bit PPA packages for 19.10+, so add-apt-repository will be useless. Users who would want to use a 32 bit PC with a recent OS should use Debian instead.